# Trying to remove view from one layout and add to another

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to modify my layout on `CheckBox` clicking action.

Checking action works fine, but unchecking gives an error:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
> parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
> ```

Here's my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        presenter.onCukRulesClicked();

        final LinearLayout checkboxesContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.checkboxes_container);

        final LinearLayout rootView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2345);

        final LinearLayout leftContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_container);

        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            if (isChecked) {
                leftContainer.removeView(checkboxesContainer);
                leftContainer.invalidate();
                rootView.addView(checkboxesContainer);
            } else {
                rootView.removeView(checkboxesContainer);
                rootView.invalidate();
                leftContainer.addView(checkboxesContainer);
            }
    }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: put layout xmls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with `removeView(view)` action delay made by Android transitions. It happens only on newer Android system version devices.

The solution is quite simple. Instead of `invalidate()` views, I removed transitions using `rootView.setLayoutTransition(null)`.

Here's the code:

```
 if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            if (isChecked) {
                leftContainer.removeView(checkboxesContainer);
                rootView.addView(checkboxesContainer);
            } else {
                rootView.setLayoutTransition(null);
                rootView.removeView(checkboxesContainer);
                leftContainer.addView(checkboxesContainer);
            }
```